# Fa-Spin on hover link text too, not only when hover icon

Tags: css

```js
$('.fa-spinner').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('fa-spin');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-spin');
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
     <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 1</a></td></tr>
     <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 2</a></td></tr>
     <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 3</a></td></tr>
     <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 4</a></td></tr>
     <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 5</a></td></tr>
    </table>
```

i have code like this

```
<table class="table">
 <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 1</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 2</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 3</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 4</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 5</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

i want to add animation `fa-spin` when hover link with this juery code

```
$('.fa-spinner').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fa-spin');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-spin');
});
```

the problem is it's still lacking than what i intent 
when i hover mouse on label text `Mylink 1` etc, 
it's not add class `fa-spin` in `<i>` tag 
it's only add `fa-spin` when i hover mouse in `fa-spinner` icon

how should i do it properly?

Comment: It may be sensible to do this with CSS rather than have to invoke jquery. Could you show us what the fa-spin class does in terms of the CSS?

Comment: @AHaworth it's just animate rotating `fa-spinner' icon....i see documentation here https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/style/animate

Comment: Could you give us the code you are using actually in your question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the function for links. To achieve that you can add classes to links then do:

```
<table class="table">
 <tr><td><a href="" class="fa-link"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 1</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href="" class="fa-link"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 2</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href="" class="fa-link"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 3</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href="" class="fa-link"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 4</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href="" class="fa-link"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Mylink 5</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Then your js code :

```
$('.fa-link').hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".fa-spinner").addClass('fa-spin');
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".fa-spinner").removeClass('fa-spin');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without JS, but only with CSS, there is an example`.fa-spinner:hover, a:hover .fa-spinner{animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;}`

Comment: it;s still not have hover effect on label/text link, only add animation spin if i hover on icon

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my previous response, now it works also when you hover text.